# Accessing key names dynamically in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

**Python{ 'Good' : '0', 'Bad' :'9', 'Lazy' : '7'}
I need to access the key names dynamically in a program. Eg.**

```
a= raw_input (" which is the final attribute:")
for i in python.items():
    if python.items()[i] == a:
        finalAttribute = python.items()[i]
```

**This giving me error saying**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/test1.py", line 11, in <module>
if somedict.items()[i] == a:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
d = { 'Good' : '0', 'Bad' :'9', 'Lazy' : '7'}
for key in d:
   print "{0} = {1}".format(key, d[key])
```

Also, I don't know what you meant when you named your variable "finalAttribute", but I feel obliged to remind you that Python makes no guarantees about the order of dictionary keys.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the indexing operator:

```
a = raw_input("which is the final attribute: ")
final_attribute = python[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab dictionary keys with `.keys()`

```
a = { 'Good' : '0', 'Bad' :'9', 'Lazy' : '7'}
a.keys()
['Good', 'Bad', 'Lazy']
```

One thing to note though is that dictionaries don't have an order, so you shouldn't be depending on the order that things are returned.

With that being said I don't entirely understand your question based on your example.

Comment: Hey--give me my gravatar back!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're misunderstanding how for-each loops work: `i` is the actual item, not an index.

But besides for that, `i` in your code is a key-value pair, expressed as a tuple (e.g. `('Good', 0)`). You only want the keys. Try:

```
a= raw_input (" which is the final attribute:") 
for i in python.keys(): 
    if i == a: 
        finalAttribute = i
```

Comment: Dictionaries iterate over their own keys -- `for i in python:` is sufficient and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be written in a simpler form:

```
a= raw_input (" which is the final attribute:")
for (x),z in python.items():
    if z == a:  
        finalAttribute = x
```

Note: Your values are in String not Integer